# Simple Twitter Streaming API Script

Tags: php, twitter

I would like to create a page that displays the latest tweet using a specific hash tag.

I currently have one working, but it uses the Search API. Problem with that is that it's not really real time, so I'd like to move it over to **Streaming API**.

I have seen online examples but they all seem to have databases and stuff. I didn't want that. Just something really simple.

Could anyone direct me in the right path or even better, show me an example?

Thanks.

Comment: If you want people to spend their time writing your code, you might try offering a bounty :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the streaming API requires that you keep the connection active. This requires a server process with an infinite loop, to get the latest tweets.

Assuming that this is possible for you (doubt it, it hardly ever works on normal webhosts), and you want to do it without a database, you'll still have to get the data from this backend script to your frontend scripts. You could probably use a .txt file for that.

**You always need a backend to use the streaming API.** It cannot (should not) be used in a normal PHP script.

Answer (score 1):

[Try this](http://140dev.com/free-twitter-api-source-code-library/twitter-display/)
 .Please go through the documentation(very easy to comprehend).It does involve database but there is hardly anything that you need to code.It is indeed very simple!

**Scripting language used:** PHP

**Library used:** Phirehose

Answer (score -1):

Well the simplest solution that I can think of is AJAX. You'll need a CGI script (or a program) that retrieves data from the [Twitter Streaming API](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/streaming-api). In the methods you'll find `statuses/filter` which will return an array of statuses, for your keywords.

Take the output from the CGI script, parse it and put the information in an array in Javascript. As a new status comes in, drop the last one out. Constantly check with the CGI script to retrieve new statuses, handle their processing and place them on the page.

I don't think anyone would write such a specific code unless you offer a generous bounty, like @rdlowry said in his comment. :)

**However**, I do recommend that you write this on your own. It will teach you to solve similar problems, how to approach such problems and how to read an API documentation (which is also very very important).

All the best.